# Adapter Data into PDF with iText

Tags: android, itext

Im generating a PDF in my Android Application with iText. I need to add a LIST to the pdf. This list needs to come form data I allready have in an Adapter. My Adapter is Allready filled with the correct data so I just need to know how to Add that Data from the Adapter to my PDF file in a LIST form of even Cells regardsless. PS: It's Dynamic Data that's fill in another part of the Application. So this data just need to be displayed in the PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the way to add data in PDF table..

```
private static void descriptionTable(Document p,ArrayList<String> list) throws BadElementException 
      {
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

            table.setWidthPercentage(100);

            PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Site Address",ele_noraml_black));
            c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            c1.setColspan(1);
            c1.setBorderWidth(1);
            c1.setPaddingBottom(10);
            c1.setBorderColor(celalBorderColor);
            table.addCell(c1);



            c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list_tree_tree.get(0),ele_noraml_black));
            c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            c1.setBorderWidth(1);
            c1.setColspan(2);
            c1.setPaddingBottom(10);
            c1.setBorderColor(celalBorderColor);
            table.addCell(c1);
 try {
                p.add(table);
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: Super. Thank you Mehul. Working. Nice.